# GAE/P3 dependency conflicts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip

I have a GAE standard Python 3 app.  When I deploy with

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project XXX
```

and this for my requirements.txt:

```
Werkzeug==1.0.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
google-cloud-ndb==1.10.5
google-cloud-tasks==2.6.0
firebase-admin==5.0.3
```

I now get this error:

```
Updating service [default]...
WARNING: Found incompatible dependencies: 
google-cloud-datastore 1.15.3 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.1.1.
google-cloud-core 1.7.2 has requirement google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.21.0, but you have google-api-core 2.1.1.
google-cloud-core 1.7.2 has requirement google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.24.0, but you have google-auth 2.3.0.
```

Although my app appears to be working, I'd like to get rid of these errors just in case.

I don't get these errors on my Mac, and nothing requires google-api-core 2.1.1.

The output of `pipdeptree | fgrep api-core` is:

```
  - google-api-core [required: >=1.22.1,<3.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
    - google-api-core [required: >=1.21.0,<3.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
    - google-api-core [required: >=1.26.0,<3.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
      - google-api-core [required: >=1.21.0,<2.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
    - google-api-core [required: >=1.29.0,<3.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
      - google-api-core [required: >=1.21.0,<2.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
    - google-api-core [required: >=1.14.0,<2.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
      - google-api-core [required: >=1.21.0,<2.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
  - google-api-core [required: >=1.26.0,<3.0.0dev, installed: 1.31.3]
```

My requirements.txt is shown below.

Is there a combination of versions of google-cloud-ndb, google-cloud-tasks, and firebase-admin that work together?

Comment: Try adding a line specifying the version of google-api-core as the first line, then remove the version numbers from google-cloud-ndb,  google-cloud-tasks, and firebase-admin.

Comment: @JohnHanley, that may work, but I'd like to have fixed versions for all packages since updated packages have the potential to break a deployed app.  Ideally, there is a combination of versions of google-cloud-ndb, google-cloud-tasks, and firebase-admin that work together.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

When version numbers are not explicitly set in `requirements.txt`, the system will install the most recent version. And sometimes, the most recent version of one package is not compatible to another package.

In your project, `google-api-core 2.1.1` is automatically installed but your version of `google-cloud-datastore` needs something lower than `2.0.0` but a minimum of `1.14.0`. The same logic goes with the warnings related to `google-cloud-core 1.7.2`.

To fix this, you should explicitly set the version numbers for the mentioned packages using the version range provided in the warning message. You'll have to pick something that works for you. For example, you can have `google-api-core 1.14.0` in your  `requirements.txt` file but this assumes that there is nothing in your code that needs a feature that is in a higher release.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the versions of `google-api-core` and `google-auth` gets rid of the version incompatibilities.  It looks like there are a lot of changes with version 2 of these libraries (which are new as of a few months ago), and that firebase hasn't caught up yet so I fixed the most recent 1.* version.

Here is a working `requirements.txt` using latest libraries:

```
Werkzeug==1.0.1
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
google-api-core==1.31.5   # Avoid conflicts
google-auth==1.35.0       # Avoid conflicts
google-cloud-ndb==1.11.1
google-cloud-tasks==2.7.1
firebase-admin==5.2.0
```

I wish `pip` could figure this stuff out...